# Amazon SES email receipt rules with separate action for separate email address

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use `Amazon SES` for my `Java Web Application`. I have verified my domain, created a bucket, created receipt rules and completed all the configurations to receive emails through SES. I am able to receive emails through SES now. My receipt rule is to store all the incoming emails to a specified s3 bucket. Now I would like to set separate receipt rule for different email address under the same domain. For example, if my verified mail domain is `mydomain.com`. I want all the emails to be stored in a common bucket named `mybucket`. Now, I want to store all emails coming to `email1@mydomain.com` as `Mail1/Inbox/email1`,`Mail1/Inbox/email2` etc. Similarly, I want to store all emails coming to `email2@mydomain.com` as `Mail2/Inbox/email1`,
`Mail2/Inbox/email2`. Is this possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. Assuming you have two email addresses `email1@mydomain.com` and `email2@mydomain.com`, this is how your setup will look like:

- One active *receipt rule set*.
- Two *receipt rules* in this *receipt rule set*. Each will have:

  - A *recipient* (`email1@mydomain.com` or `email2@mydomain.com`).
  - An *S3 action*, with *S3 Bucket* as `mybucket` and *Object Key Prefix* as `Mail1/Inbox/email1` or `Mail2/Inbox/email2`.

Relevant documentation:

- From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html):

> You set up receipt rules to specify how to handle the mail when a condition is satisfied. A receipt rule consists of a condition and an ordered list of actions. If the recipient to whom the incoming mail is addressed matches a recipient specified in the condition, then Amazon SES performs the actions specified in the rule.
>
> Receipt rules are grouped together into receipt rule sets. You can define multiple receipt rule sets for your AWS account, but only one receipt rule set is active at any time.

- More details on setting this up [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-receipt-rules.html).
- S3 related details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html).